# Decided to update HttpWebRequest to HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net-core, https

I updated my Instagram API and I read that `HttpClient` is now the preferred way in .NET Core 3.1. I would like to get a code review, because there are too many examples and too many ways and I'm not quite sure if I did the migration correctly.

One more question: The reason I added `_client.Timeout` is in case the user is using proxy and it is not responding. I think that it's needed only on the first request. Can I somehow restrict it to the first request? Or a better way?

New code:

```
public class InstagramAPI
{
    private static HttpClient _client;

    public string Username { get; private set; }
    public string Password { get; private set; }

    public InstagramAPI(string username, string password, string proxy = null)
    {
        if (_client == null)
        {
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler();

            if (proxy != null)
            {
                handler.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxy, true);
            }

            if (handler.SupportsAutomaticDecompression)
            {
                handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
            }

            _client = new HttpClient(handler)
            {
                Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
            };
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username))
            throw new ArgumentException("Username cannot be empty or null.");

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password))
            throw new ArgumentException("Password cannot be empty or null.");

        Username = username;
        Password = password;
    }

    public void Login()
    {
        try
        {
            // 1st request
            HttpRequestMessage httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://www.instagram.com/");

            httpRequest.Headers.Host = "www.instagram.com";
            httpRequest.Headers.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0");
            httpRequest.Headers.Accept.ParseAdd("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
            httpRequest.Headers.AcceptLanguage.ParseAdd("en-US");
            httpRequest.Headers.AcceptEncoding.ParseAdd("gzip, deflate, br");

            httpRequest.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");

            var getsResponse = _client.SendAsync(httpRequest);
            var getResult = getsResponse.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            string web_key_id = Regex.Match(getResult, "\"key_id\":\"([^\"]*)").Groups[1].Value;
            string web_pub_key = Regex.Match(getResult, "\"public_key\":\"([^\"]*)").Groups[1].Value;
            string web_key_version = Regex.Match(getResult, "\"version\":\"([^\"]*)").Groups[1].Value;
            string csrfToken = Regex.Match(getResult, "\"csrf_token\":\"([^\"]*)").Groups[1].Value;
            string rolloutHash = Regex.Match(getResult, "\"rollout_hash\":\"([^\"]*)").Groups[1].Value;

            // 2nd request
            string encryptedPassword = EncryptPassword(Password, web_pub_key, web_key_id, web_key_version);
            HttpRequestMessage httpRequest2 = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/");

            httpRequest2.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", Username),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("enc_password", encryptedPassword),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("queryParams", "{}"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("optIntoOneTap", "false")
            });

            httpRequest2.Headers.Host = "www.instagram.com";
            httpRequest2.Headers.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0");
            httpRequest2.Headers.Accept.ParseAdd("*/*");
            httpRequest2.Headers.AcceptLanguage.ParseAdd("en-US");
            httpRequest2.Headers.AcceptEncoding.ParseAdd("gzip, deflate, br");

            httpRequest2.Headers.Add("X-CSRFToken", csrfToken);
            httpRequest2.Headers.ConnectionClose = true;

            var postResponse = _client.SendAsync(httpRequest2);
            var postResult = postResponse.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            
            ...
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            if (ex.InnerException is TaskCanceledException)
            {
                // return proxy error
                MessageBox.Show("We could not connect. It could a proxy problem, if you were using one.", "Connection error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

Old code:

````
void Login(string postData)
{
    // 1st request
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.instagram.com/") as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

    if (proxyAddress != null)
    {
        request.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxyAddress);
    }
    else
    {
        // The first request takes an abnormally long time: This occurs because WebRequest by default detects and loads proxy settings the first time it starts,
        // which can take quite a while.To stop this, simply set the proxy property (WebRequest.Proxy) to null and it'll bypass the check
        request.Proxy = null;
    }

    request.Host = "www.instagram.com";
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0";
    request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";

    request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US");
    request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");

    CookieCollection cookies = new CookieCollection();

    IAsyncResult response = request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), request);

    // this line implements the timeout, if there is a timeout, the callback fires and the request becomes aborted
    ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(response.AsyncWaitHandle, new WaitOrTimerCallback(TimeoutCallback), request, 2000, true);

    // The response came in the allowed time. The work processing will happen in the callback function
    _manualResetEvent.WaitOne();

    if (RequestResult == null)
    {
        return ResultType.ProxyError;
    }

    string web_key_id = Regex.Match(RequestResult, "\"key_id\":\"([^\"]*)").Groups[1].Value;
    string web_pub_key = Regex.Match(RequestResult, "\"public_key\":\"([^\"]*)").Groups[1].Value;
    string web_key_version = Regex.Match(RequestResult, "\"version\":\"([^\"]*)").Groups[1].Value;
    string csrfToken = Regex.Match(RequestResult, "\"csrf_token\":\"([^\"]*)").Groups[1].Value;
    string rolloutHash = Regex.Match(RequestResult, "\"rollout_hash\":\"([^\"]*)").Groups[1].Value;

    // 2nd request
    string encryptedPassword = GenerateEncPassword(password, web_pub_key, web_key_id, web_key_version);

    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

    HttpWebRequest request2 = WebRequest.Create("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/") as HttpWebRequest;
    request2.Method = "POST";
    request2.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

    if (proxyAddress != null)
    {
        request2.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxyAddress);
    }
    else
    {
        request2.Proxy = null;
    }

    request2.Host = "www.instagram.com";
    request2.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0";
    request2.Accept = "*/*";
    request2.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request2.Referer = "https://www.instagram.com/";

    request2.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US");
    request2.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
    request2.Headers.Add("X-CSRFToken", csrfToken);

    request2.ContentLength = data.Length;

    try
    {
        using (Stream stream = request2.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        using (HttpWebResponse response2 = request2.GetResponseWithoutException() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response2.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                RequestResult = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        if (e.InnerException is SocketException)
        {
            return ResultType.ProxyError;
        }

        return ResultType.ProxyError;
    }
    
    ...
}

private ManualResetEvent _manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

public string RequestResult { get; private set; }

private void TimeoutCallback(object state, bool timedOut)
{
    if (timedOut)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)state;
        if (request != null)
        {
            request.Abort();
        }
    }
}

private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asyncResult.AsyncState;

    try
    {
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                RequestResult = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }

    _manualResetEvent.Set();
}
```
````

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers (even if you already made changes prior to the answer), doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) as well as  [_what you may and may not do after receiving answers_](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765).

Comment: Not worthy of being an actual review so I'll post this as a comment: ["The PascalCasing convention capitalizes the first character of each word (including **acronyms over two letters in length**)"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions)

Comment: @BCdotWEB, did you mean those 3 variables which are in snake case?

Comment: @nop Things like "API".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var postResponse = _client.SendAsync(httpRequest2);
var postResult = postResponse.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

*Never* use tasks like this, it leads to dead-locks very easily. Plus it's wasteful, you have an entire framework (`HttpClient`) designed to keep your application responsive, and instead you freeze it for no good reason.

1. Make your `Login` function `async` and have it return a `Task<bool>` (or even better, an enum that describes exactly why it failed if it did)
2. Properly `await` those `async` calls (`SendAsync` and `ReadAsStringAsync`)
3. Change `Login` to `LoginAsync` to follow the framework naming conventions
4. Get rid of those random `MessageBox` calls in your class, they do nothing but prevent unit testing and introduce WinForms dependencies in what could otherwise be a nice service class.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer! I actually did the `await` part right after I wrote the question. Fair point about the MessageBox's. Updated the code in the question, thanks again and I'm open for more corrections!

Comment: You still have a `postResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result`!

Comment: Also instead of doing those repeated and error-prone `Contains` calls, decode the response (I'm assuming it's JSON) and read the structured properties directly.

Comment: Oh thanks, fixed the `ReadAsStringAsync()`. The result is indeed JSON, e.g. `{"message": "checkpoint_required", "checkpoint_url": "/challenge/7062375696/FELrUZykgu/", "lock": false, "status": "fail"}`. What do you mean by read directly? To return the object.message instead of `ResultType`?

Comment: No, I mean use `JsonConverter.Deserialize<T>(jsonString)`, where `T` is a class you write that contains the fields you're interested in from the response (like `string Message;` etc), and then use the class to determine the return value instead of doing string operations.

Comment: And if you're not familiar with JSON parsing, make sure you define a clear enum for the status, don't parse it as a string, that will lead to more `if..else if..else if..`

Comment: Incidentally, .NET 5 is getting sync APIs on HttpClient (finally); but it's not clear if using them here is an advantage or not.

Answer (score 3):

I don't want to repeat Blindly's observations (and those that have spotted under the comment section).

I would like to suggest other improvement areas:

### Constructor

You are using instance constructor to initialize static member.

- Static constructor should be used to initialize your `HttpClient` with(out) proxy
- There is no need to use instance constructor

  - `UserName` and `Password` should be a parameter of the `Login`

### Login - In general

It does seems to me that you want to implement something on the server-side which was designed to support client-side authentication.

- Please check that does Instagram support server-side auth

### Login - Error handling

This error handling is really naive and thin.

- You should definitely look for `HttpRequestException`.
- You should check the responses' `StatusCode` before any further processing

### Login - Flow

Separation helps the understanding and maintainability of a function. Smaller chunks can be easier tested, etc.

- I suggest to separate the two separate requests into two separate functions
- Your `Login` should be the coordinator for the two functions

### HttpClient - Header

You are using a lot of strings to setup requests. Most of them are duplicated.

- Please consider to use constants instead
- Consider to set the `Host` on the `HttpClient` level instead of on the `HttpWebRequest` level

### HttpClient - Timeout

In case of .NET Core the recommended approach to enforce timeout is to use the [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Timeout) library. It is a quite neat utility and it exposes other useful policies as well (like circuit-breaker, bulkhead)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! I applied your constructor and error handling suggestions, excluding the status codes because Instagram returns kinda random status codes in case of two-factor authentication/checkpoint required or so. They are returning the response as JSON. I like the single responsibility concept (S.O.L.I.D.) for the login function. Constants would also be awesome as you mentioned. Do you recommend me to put the constants into that class or a different class with singleton pattern implementation? I will definitely try out Polly.

Comment: @nop 1) It does not matter from where the status code is coming. It is the primary indicator of the request processing successfulness. For example if it is 5xx then you shouldn't looking for `key_id` in the response body. 2) SRP is a kind a good guidance for every length function :D 3) If you need to reuse these constants across multiple classes then move them into a separate class and mark it as `static`. You don't have to make it as singleton.

Comment: Fair point. Btw, is it only me who cannot find a way to set up proxy only for `HttpRequestMessage` instead of the whole `HttpClient` object? In case it is like that, I will probably have to move the HttpClient instance into the LoginAsync method.

Comment: What are the advantages of using Polly to set the timeout instead of simply using the property? Polly is nice if you're using the more advanced features (at which point an argument could be made to be consistent and use it for everything), but in this case it's overkill with no benefits. Sidenote: Static constructors are pretty awful from a performance PoV so if one can avoid it, that's a good idea - just use `Lazy` instead.

Comment: @Voo It would make sense if you would use Polly's timeout in combination with a retry policy. Retry could fire if the status code is either 408, 500, 503, 504. Then you can define per request timeout and global timeouts (for all retrry attempts).

Comment: @Peter Sure if you're going to use the extra features, it makes sense to be consistent. But if nothing but a simple timeout is needed the property will do just fine imo.